# how to use ralouphie/getallheaders package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm trying to find an example with this https://github.com/ralouphie/getallheaders package into the laravel

Well I have installed package, able to see it in the vendor directory

call a function into the controller

`$userHeaders = getallheaders();`

`dd($userHeaders);`

but when I'm trying to debug the getallheaders() function it didn't return anything

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) {

    /**
     * Removed actual code and try to return a simple string 
     */
    function getallheaders()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }

?>
```

Don't know what is wrong, any help would be great!

Comment: run `composer dumpautoload` and then try again.

Comment: already did this, also tried to delete vendor and did composer install

Comment: when you do `dd( function_exists('getallheaders') )` what do you get? true or false?

Comment: ```dd( function_exists('getallheaders') )``` >> true